# Unbale to deploy MERN application on Heroku. reactHelpers package not installed

Tags: reactjs, heroku, deployment, mern

This is the first time I am working with Heroku. I have followed the instructions on how to deploy my application on Heroku. But I keep on getting an error when deploying. The log file states the I need to install ReactHelpers but I have never needed to install this package. It also tells me to install by running: npm install ../utils/reactHelpers. But I cannot run this command in my project.

The error message is as follows:

```
./node_modules/@material-ui/core/esm/Slider/Slider.js

Cannot find module: '../utils/reactHelpers'. Make sure this package is installed.
```

This is the error log:

```
-----> Node.js app detected

       

-----> Creating runtime environment

       

       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error

       NODE_ENV=production

       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true

       NODE_VERBOSE=false

       

-----> Installing binaries

       engines.node (package.json):  unspecified

       engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)

       

       Resolving node version 12.x...

       Downloading and installing node 12.18.3...

       Using default npm version: 6.14.6

       

-----> Installing dependencies

       Prebuild detected (node_modules already exists)

       Rebuilding any native modules

       body-parser@1.19.0 /tmp/build_6d259321/node_modules/body-parser

       bytes@3.1.0 /tmp/build_6d259321/node_modules/bytes

       content-type@1.0.4 /tmp/build_6d259321/node_modules/content-type

       debug@2.6.9 /tmp/build_6d259321/node_modules/debug

       ms@2.0.0 /tmp/build_6d259321/node_modules/ms

       depd@1.1.2 /tmp/build_6d259321/node_modules/depd

       http-errors@1.7.2 /tmp/build_6d259321/node_modules/http-errors

       inherits@2.0.3 /tmp/build_6d259321/node_modules/inherits

       setprototypeof@1.1.1 /tmp/build_6d259321/node_modules/setprototypeof

       statuses@1.5.0 /tmp/build_6d259321/node_modules/statuses

       toidentifier@1.0.0 /tmp/build_6d259321/node_modules/toidentifier

       iconv-lite@0.4.24 /tmp/build_6d259321/node_modules/iconv-lite

       safer-buffer@2.1.2 /tmp/build_6d259321/node_modules/safer-buffer

       on-finished@2.3.0 /tmp/build_6d259321/node_modules/on-finished

       ee-first@1.1.1 /tmp/build_6d259321/node_modules/ee-first

       qs@6.7.0 /tmp/build_6d259321/node_modules/qs

       raw-body@2.4.0 /tmp/build_6d259321/node_modules/raw-body

       unpipe@1.0.0 /tmp/build_6d259321/node_modules/unpipe

       type-is@1.6.18 /tmp/build_6d259321/node_modules/type-is

       media-typer@0.3.0 /tmp/build_6d259321/node_modules/media-typer

       mime-types@2.1.27 /tmp/build_6d259321/node_modules/mime-types

       mime-db@1.44.0 /tmp/build_6d259321/node_modules/mime-db

       express@4.17.1 /tmp/build_6d259321/node_modules/express

       accepts@1.3.7 /tmp/build_6d259321/node_modules/accepts

       negotiator@0.6.2 /tmp/build_6d259321/node_modules/negotiator

       array-flatten@1.1.1 /tmp/build_6d259321/node_modules/array-flatten

       content-disposition@0.5.3 /tmp/build_6d259321/node_modules/content-disposition

       safe-buffer@5.1.2 /tmp/build_6d259321/node_modules/safe-buffer

       cookie@0.4.0 /tmp/build_6d259321/node_modules/cookie

       cookie-signature@1.0.6 /tmp/build_6d259321/node_modules/cookie-signature

       encodeurl@1.0.2 /tmp/build_6d259321/node_modules/encodeurl

       escape-html@1.0.3 /tmp/build_6d259321/node_modules/escape-html

       etag@1.8.1 /tmp/build_6d259321/node_modules/etag

       finalhandler@1.1.2 /tmp/build_6d259321/node_modules/finalhandler

       parseurl@1.3.3 /tmp/build_6d259321/node_modules/parseurl

       fresh@0.5.2 /tmp/build_6d259321/node_modules/fresh

       merge-descriptors@1.0.1 /tmp/build_6d259321/node_modules/merge-descriptors

       methods@1.1.2 /tmp/build_6d259321/node_modules/methods

       path-to-regexp@0.1.7 /tmp/build_6d259321/node_modules/path-to-regexp

       proxy-addr@2.0.6 /tmp/build_6d259321/node_modules/proxy-addr

       forwarded@0.1.2 /tmp/build_6d259321/node_modules/forwarded

       ipaddr.js@1.9.1 /tmp/build_6d259321/node_modules/ipaddr.js

       range-parser@1.2.1 /tmp/build_6d259321/node_modules/range-parser

       send@0.17.1 /tmp/build_6d259321/node_modules/send

       destroy@1.0.4 /tmp/build_6d259321/node_modules/destroy

       mime@1.6.0 /tmp/build_6d259321/node_modules/mime

       ms@2.1.1 /tmp/build_6d259321/node_modules/send/node_modules/ms

       serve-static@1.14.1 /tmp/build_6d259321/node_modules/serve-static

       utils-merge@1.0.1 /tmp/build_6d259321/node_modules/utils-merge

       vary@1.1.2 /tmp/build_6d259321/node_modules/vary

       mongoose@5.10.1 /tmp/build_6d259321/node_modules/mongoose

       bson@1.1.5 /tmp/build_6d259321/node_modules/bson

       kareem@2.3.1 /tmp/build_6d259321/node_modules/kareem

       mongodb@3.6.0 /tmp/build_6d259321/node_modules/mongodb

       bl@2.2.1 /tmp/build_6d259321/node_modules/bl

       readable-stream@2.3.7 /tmp/build_6d259321/node_modules/readable-stream

       core-util-is@1.0.2 /tmp/build_6d259321/node_modules/core-util-is

       isarray@1.0.0 /tmp/build_6d259321/node_modules/isarray

       process-nextick-args@2.0.1 /tmp/build_6d259321/node_modules/process-nextick-args

       string_decoder@1.1.1 /tmp/build_6d259321/node_modules/string_decoder

       util-deprecate@1.0.2 /tmp/build_6d259321/node_modules/util-deprecate

       denque@1.4.1 /tmp/build_6d259321/node_modules/denque

       require_optional@1.0.1 /tmp/build_6d259321/node_modules/require_optional

       resolve-from@2.0.0 /tmp/build_6d259321/node_modules/resolve-from

       semver@5.7.1 /tmp/build_6d259321/node_modules/semver

       mongoose-legacy-pluralize@1.0.2 /tmp/build_6d259321/node_modules/mongoose-legacy-pluralize

       mpath@0.7.0 /tmp/build_6d259321/node_modules/mpath

       mquery@3.2.2 /tmp/build_6d259321/node_modules/mquery

       bluebird@3.5.1 /tmp/build_6d259321/node_modules/bluebird

       debug@3.1.0 /tmp/build_6d259321/node_modules/mquery/node_modules/debug

       regexp-clone@1.0.0 /tmp/build_6d259321/node_modules/regexp-clone

       sliced@1.0.1 /tmp/build_6d259321/node_modules/sliced

       ms@2.1.2 /tmp/build_6d259321/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/ms

       safe-buffer@5.2.1 /tmp/build_6d259321/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/safe-buffer

       sift@7.0.1 /tmp/build_6d259321/node_modules/sift

       memory-pager@1.5.0 /tmp/build_6d259321/node_modules/memory-pager

       saslprep@1.0.3 /tmp/build_6d259321/node_modules/saslprep

       sparse-bitfield@3.0.3 /tmp/build_6d259321/node_modules/sparse-bitfield

       Installing any new modules (package.json)

       audited 78 packages in 0.902s

       

       2 packages are looking for funding

         run `npm fund` for details

       

       found 0 vulnerabilities

       

       

-----> Build

       Detected both "build" and "heroku-postbuild" scripts

       Running heroku-postbuild

       

       > inschrijvingen@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild /tmp/build_6d259321

       > npm run install-client && npm run build

       

       

       > inschrijvingen@1.0.0 install-client /tmp/build_6d259321

       > cd client && npm install

       

       added 32 packages from 25 contributors and audited 1775 packages in 20.51s

       

       72 packages are looking for funding

         run `npm fund` for details

       

       found 0 vulnerabilities

       

       

       > inschrijvingen@1.0.0 build /tmp/build_6d259321

       > cd client && npm run build

       

       

       > inschrijvingen_react@0.1.0 build /tmp/build_6d259321/client

       > react-scripts build

       

       Creating an optimized production build...

       Failed to compile.

       

       ./node_modules/@material-ui/core/esm/Slider/Slider.js

       Cannot find module: '../utils/reactHelpers'. Make sure this package is installed.

       

       You can install this package by running: npm install ../utils/reactHelpers.

       

       

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! errno 1

npm ERR! inschrijvingen_react@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`

npm ERR! Exit status 1

npm ERR! 

npm ERR! Failed at the inschrijvingen_react@0.1.0 build script.

npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.kC8EO/_logs/2020-08-31T12_35_36_374Z-debug.log

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! errno 1

npm ERR! inschrijvingen@1.0.0 build: `cd client && npm run build`

npm ERR! Exit status 1

npm ERR! 

npm ERR! Failed at the inschrijvingen@1.0.0 build script.

npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.kC8EO/_logs/2020-08-31T12_35_36_393Z-debug.log

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! errno 1

npm ERR! inschrijvingen@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild: `npm run install-client && npm run build`

npm ERR! Exit status 1

npm ERR! 

npm ERR! Failed at the inschrijvingen@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild script.

npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.kC8EO/_logs/2020-08-31T12_35_36_414Z-debug.log

-----> Build failed

       

       We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:

       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys

       

       Some possible problems:

       

       - node_modules checked into source control

         https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/node-best-practices#only-git-the-important-bits

       

       - Node version not specified in package.json

         https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-a-node-js-version

       

       - A module may be missing from 'dependencies' in package.json

         https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys#ensure-you-aren-t-relying-on-untracked-dependencies

       

       Love,

       Heroku

       

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.

 !     Push failed
```

Comment: Check here [How I resolved issue with module](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68873783/9427495).

Answer (score 0):

This is a module required by your instance of the `@material-ui` library, and it can't be found. Try deleting your `node_modules` folder and running `npm i` again. This will reinstall your dependency tree and hopefully fix the problem you're having.